# How to solve a second order differential equation on Scilab?

Tags: numerical-methods, differential-equations, scilab, numerical-integration, runge-kutta

I need to solve this differential equation using Runge-Kytta 4(5) on Scilab:

[image]

The initial conditions are above. The interval  and the h-step are:

[image]

[image]

I don't need to implement Runge-Kutta. I just need to solve this and plot the result on the plane:

[image]

I tried to follow these instructions on the official "Scilab Help":

https://x-engineer.org/graduate-engineering/programming-languages/scilab/solve-second-order-ordinary-differential-equation-ode-scilab/

The suggested code is:

```
// Import the diagram and set the ending time
loadScicos();
loadXcosLibs();
importXcosDiagram("SCI/modules/xcos/examples/solvers/ODE_Example.zcos");
scs_m.props.tf = 5000;

// Select the solver Runge-Kutta and set the precision
scs_m.props.tol(6) = 6;
scs_m.props.tol(7) = 10^-2;

// Start the timer, launch the simulation and display time
tic();
try xcos_simulate(scs_m, 4); catch disp(lasterror()); end
t = toc();
disp(t, "Time for Runge-Kutta:");
```

However, it is not clear for me how I can change this for the specific differential equation that I showed above. I have a very basic knowledge of Scilab.

The final plot should be something like the picture bellow, an ellipse:

[image]

Just to provide some mathematical context, this is the differential equation that describes the pendulum problem.

Could someone help me, please?

=========

**UPDATE**

Based on @luizpauloml comments, I am updating this post.
I need to convert the second-order ODE into a system of first-order ODEs and then I need to write a function to represent such system.

So, I know how to do this on pen and paper. Hence, using z as a variable:

[image]

OK, but how do I write a normal script?

The Xcos is quite disposable. I only kept it because I was trying to mimic the example on the official Scilab page.

Comment: The code you show uses Xcos to solve the ODE. Is that what you want? Or just running a regular script is enough?

Comment: And basically, what you should do is convert a second-order ODE into a system of first-order ODEs, then write a function to represent such system.

Comment: @luispauloml, thanks [or may I say, obrigado =)]. I updated my post. I know how to do the conversion you said. The XCos is disposable, I don't need it. Running a regular script is enough. I just need to use Runge-Kutta (4,5)

Comment: Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg 4(5) is a method with variable step size. Is there something given about the required error tolerances, is 0.1 to be the minimal step size,...?

Comment: @LutzL you can check [`ode()` help](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/en_US/ode.html), which has more information on relative and absolute tolerance used in the methods available.

Comment: Per the documentation, the method to use is "fix", however I don't understand the name choice as per the limited information it is still an adaptive step-size method. Why the embedded explicit method "rkf" demands the (inexpensive) Jacobians is also not immediately evident. As for my request for information, it is not clear what the intent behind the task is: just implement some ODE for the numerical solver, or showcase the limitations of numerical solvers, or showcase some specific form of discretization error,...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, you need to use `ode()`, which can employ many methods, Runge-Kutta included. First, you need to define a function to represent the system of ODEs, and *Step 1* in the link you provided shows you what to do:

```
function z = f(t,y)
    //f(t,z) represents the sysmte of ODEs:
    //    -the first argument should always be the independe variable
    //    -the second argument should always be the dependent variables
    //    -it may have more than two arguments
    //    -y is a vector 2x1: y(1) = theta, y(2) = theta'
    //    -z is a vector 2x1: z(1) = z    , z(2) = z'

    z(1) = y(2)         //first equation:  z  = theta'
    z(2) = 10*sin(y(1)) //second equation: z' = 10*sin(theta)
endfunction
```

Notice that even if `t` (the independent variable) does not explicitly appear in your system of ODEs, it still needs to be an argument of `f()`. Now you just use `ode()`, setting the flag `'rk'` or `'rkf'` to use either one of the available Runge-Kutta methods:

```
ts = linspace(0,3,200);
theta0  = %pi/4;
dtheta0 = 0;
y0 = [theta0; dtheta0];
t0 = 0;
thetas = ode('rk',y0, t0, ts, f); //the output have the same order
                                  //as the argument `y` of f()

scf(1); clf();
plot2d(thetas(2,:),thetas(1,:),-5);
xtitle('Phase portrait', 'theta''(t)','theta(t)');
xgrid();
```

The output:

[image: Phase portrait of a gravity pendulum]